# Woocommerece category page showing in stock product as out of stock

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

All variations of the product has a stock. but still it is showing out of stock in wordpress backend and in product category page, but when we go to the single product page that product is available we can buy that product.

Things i tried:

- Changed Theme
- Created Duplicate of the "in stock" product but that new product also
  shows out of stock
- Deactivated all the plugins except woocommerce.
- Created New Product.

Below images are for your reference.
Stock quantity.
[image]

Backend products page.
[image]

Category page.
[image]

Single product page.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/pull/23665/files

Refer above link to solve this error.

Answer (score -2):

I have the same Problem in Magento, the reason was Views was not added in Database. Once i added Products start showing in stock.

[image]